# Reset Mysql auto increment field

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to reset the auto incrementing value of a field so it starts back at 1 ?

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| name  | varchar(45)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reset back to it's lowest possible value.

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

If you're doing it because you've deleted records with the view to resetting a table back to an empty state, then consider using [`TRUNCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate.html) in the future, which will take care of the auto increment for you.

```
TRUNCATE <tablename>;
```

Answer (score 2):

ALTER TABLE tbl_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

If the table is empty.